# Symfony 5 how paste image to twig from no public directory

Tags: php, image, symfony, twig, symfony5

The images are located in non public folder. And I want return the image to twig.

I tried use BinaryFileResponse

```
    $actualSignature = $this->getParameter('dir_signatures') .'/'.$actualSignature->getName();
    $binaryFileSignature = new BinaryFileResponse($actualSignature);
```

and return it to twig

```
return $this->render('security/profile.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView(),'signature' => $binaryFileSignature]);
```

And in twig

```
<img src="{{ signature.file }}"/>
```

Comment: try this : ``<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ signature.file }}" />`` (use png instead of jpeg if needed)

Comment: ^ You would need to convert the binary response to base64 first before trying the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a controller action that returns just an image like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("image/{imagePath}", name="show_image")
 */
public function showimageAction(string $imagePath): BinaryFileResponse
{
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse(
        $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')
        . '/'
        . $this->getParameter('dir_signatures') // related to project root dir
        . '/'
        . $imagePath
    );
    $response->setContentDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT
    );
    return $response;
}
```

Then pass to your template just image name to get:

```
return $this->render('security/profile.html.twig',[
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'signature' => $actualSignature->getName()
]);
```

And in template:

```
<img src="{{ path('show_image', {imagePath: signature}) }}"/>
```